# Getting SharePoint site data

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server

I want to know know how to find out the date when a given web was created. I want to find out who created it using C# and the date it has been created.

I am using SharePoint 2007 server with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for a console application

```
using (var site = new SPSite("http://intranet.contoso.com"))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(web.Author);
        Console.WriteLine(web.Created);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Should be working for SharePoint 2007, too.

For more information have a look at [SPWeb members (Microsoft.SharePoint) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb_members(v=office.12).aspx)